# Setting Timeout for Axis SOAP Webservice

Tags: java, soap, timeout, axis

I'm using an Axis 1.4 webservice like this:

```
FooServiceLocator fooLocator = new FooServiceLocator();
fooLocator.getEngine().setOption("sendMultiRefs", false);
Foo foo = fooLocator.getFooService(new URL(soapServiceUrl));
```

How can I set a timeout for the connection establishment and for the opened connection?
(Similar to `org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient` `setTimeout()` and `setSoTimeout()`)?

I found a hint that suggested setting a timeout like this:

```
((Stub) sPcspService).setTimeout(soapTimeoutSecs * 1000);
```

but the explicit cast looks more like a hack than on official API usage.

Grepping the source code I found references to

> `DefaultCommonsHTTPClientProperties.CONNECTION_DEFAULT_SO_TIMEOUT_KEY`

but neither do I know if I use the `Commons HTTP Client` or another, nor how to apply this option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used to use axis 1.4 and soap as well, to set timeout for stub with your example, I would do as:

```
FooServiceLocator fooLocator = new FooServiceLocator();
fooLocator.getEngine().setOption("sendMultiRefs", false);
Foo foo = fooLocator.getFooService(new URL(soapServiceUrl));

FooStub binding = (FooStub) foo;
binding.setTimeout(soapTimeoutSecs * 1000);
```

Your FooStub is extended to org.apache.axis.client.Stub and if you generated the classes via wsdl2java you would got them already.

Comment: Above solution is not working. Using Axis 1.4 & Java 1.7. In-fact, not a single approach is working for Axis read time out.. surprise ! Tried all options mentioned in below link - http://wiki.apache.org/ws/FrontPage/Axis/AxisCommonsHTTP
--/--
http://www.coderanch.com/t/544075/Web-Services/java/set-timeout-Axis-client
 --/--
https://samaxes.com/2009/04/axis-14-read-timed-out-and-http-11/